# Webpage editor friendly to all levels of web developer

Tags: windows, web-development, wysiwyg

I am in charge of a small organization at my school. We are currently in the process of making a website for our organization. I have laid out a large part of the HTML and PHP needed but now i have been assigned a team, with the objective of updating info and adding features, that has no knowledge of web development at all. So my question is: Is there a reliable, free and relatively easy to use webpage editor for windows that has WYSIWYG features AND HTML editor features?

Comment: Not an answer directly to your question so I will leave as a comment. I would strongly recommend moving to a content management system for this requirement. As you are already using PHP, you have plenty to chose from. WordPress is, of course, the standard against which others tend to be measured. But Joomla is another. There are lots

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is that there are a number of browser differences, plus platform differences, that mean that what you see might not be what everybody else sees unless you stick to a clearly defined subset of HTML.

What I would suggest is to:

1. Remove the need to edit the HTML by using a static web site generator these have a number of advantages:

   1. Consistent style across the site
   2. Editors don't need to learn HTML editing
   3. Such generators do tend to stick to the consistent parts of the HTML specification
2. I would also look to move the source content under version control ASAP - while only one person working on the site might be able to avoid problems a team is much more likely to need to be able to track and undo changes.

For a user friendly version control system that is free and available for just about every platform I would recommend [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).
For an excellent static web site generator that allows teams to work on portions of the site at the same time and is free, gratis & open source, I would suggest taking a look at the [Python](https://www.python.org/) [Hyde](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hyde/) Static Web Site Generator Tools/Library. *(The Hyde [stater kit](http://merlin.rebrovic.net/hyde-starter-kit/about.html) is well worth a look as well).*

With such a setup your team members can clone the source of the site onto their own machines, make their changes in markdown *just like here*, run a web server on their own machine to check their changes, commit their changes into mercurial and push them out to the rest of the team.

All of the above software is free, gratis and open source and available to run on anything from a RaspberryPi upwards.

Comment: Thank you! Ill give it a try next meeting and see how it goes